# Hook keyboard layout change event for specific window [Windows][x64]

Tags: windows, winapi, hook, setwindowshookex

I need to hook change keyboard layout event (change input language) for a certain window (another process) and execute some actions in the my main program.

I tried to use global hook for `WH_KERBOARD_LL` for Shift/Ctrl KeyDown and it works as needed but doesn't hook the virtual keyboard, custom shortcuts etc.
I also tried to use the global `WH_CALLWNDPROC` hook for `WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE`, but my application just doesn't get any events (without DLL). Same with the `WH_SHELL` hook. As far as I understand them doesn't work without a DLL injection.

Actually, there are several questions:

1. Is it really true that `WH_CALLWNDPROC` strictly requires a DLL? If so, is it possible to load it into a specific application? I know the HWND and ThreadID of this window (when it is Foreground). How do I get the hooked event back?
2. Are there any other tricks to hook the keyboard layout change event without a DLL?

Comment: [WH_CALLWNDPROC and WH_SHELL both can be Thread or global scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa?redirectedfrom=MSDN#remarks) but *If the dwThreadId parameter is zero or specifies the identifier of a thread created by a different process, the lpfn parameter must point to a hook procedure in a DLL*.

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT Thanks! But why then the global `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` hook works from within the application, without a DLL? Does it work somehow differently?   
And if I still need to use a DLL to load the hook into a specific `dwThreadId` how do I get that event back to my app?

Comment: [the WH_KEYBOARD_LL hook is not injected into another process. Instead, the context switches back to the process that installed the hook and it is called in its original context. Then the context switches back to the application that generated the event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644985(v=vs.85)#remarks).

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT Thanks again! So, to hook `WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE` event I need to make DLL and set `hmod` to this DLL, `lpfm` to hook function inside DLL and `dwThreadId` to window that I want to hook. Right? How do I get the event back into my main application? What are my options? IPC only?

Comment: [IPC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/interprocess-communications) is applicable for communications and data sharing between applications.